# Алгоритмическая задача

Tags: c++, база-данных, алгоритм

Вот сама задача:

Петя, которому три года, очень любит играть с машинками. Всего у Пети N различных машинок, которые хранятся на полке шкафа так высоко, что он сам не может до них дотянуться. Одновременно на полу комнаты может находиться не более K машинок. Петя играет с одной из машинок на полу и если он хочет поиграть с другой машинкой, которая также находится на полу, то дотягивается до нее сам. Если же машинка находится на полке, то он обращается за помощью к маме. Мама может достать для Пети машинку с полки и одновременно с этим поставить на полку любую машинку с пола. Мама очень хорошо знает своего ребенка и может предугадать последовательность, в которой Петя захочет играть с машинками. При этом, чтобы не мешать Петиной игре, она хочет совершить как можно меньше операций по подъему машинки с пола, каждый раз правильно выбирая машинку, которую следует убрать на полку. Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы определить минимальное количество операций. Перед тем, как Петя начал играть, все машинки стоят на полке.

Моя идея по решению этой задачи: будем ставить машинки на пол, пока все место на полу не будет занято. Когда это произойет, тогда мы уберём такую машинку, которую мы уже ставили, но такой, которой нет в дальнейшей последовательности, и вместо неё мы возьмем ту, которая нам нужна(стоит следующей в последовательности). Если нет такой машинки, то мы возьмем ту, которая дальше всех стоит в последовательности, относительно того момента, где мы сейчас находимся, и уберем её.

Реализовать я думал так: положим последовательность в массив, и посчитаем расстояние от 1-го члена последовательности до такой машинки, и если эта машинка уже на полу, положим это число в кучу.

Мне кажется я не совсем правильно реализовываю. Помогите как реализовать мой алгоритм (если он, конечно, верный)

Comment: Вроде алгоритм норм. По реализации - можно хранить k машинок в контейнере, который отсортирован по следующему номеру в последовательности хотелок Пети). Как только Петя просит следующую машину, то мы проверяем - есть ли она на полу и если нет, то удаляем самый дальний элемент в этом отсортированном контейнере.

Comment: Другой вопрос - как найти позицию определенной машины в последовательности хотелок Пети? Если каждый раз искать заново, то сложность получится O(N^2). В качестве альтернативы можно добавить ассоциативный контейнер, где ключ это номер машины, а значение - все позиции в хотелках Пети. Например: `Машина 1: 5 10 15`. Для составления такой статистики нам нужно будет пройти по всему массиву. Зато потом, когда Петя захочет `Машину 1`, то мы будем знать что потом она встретится на 10-й позиции и вставить в нужной место